# Load spread across multiple Queues that contains work items to be processed by worker threads accessing queues

Tags: java, algorithm

i have a design requirement where data from various sources need to be processed by multiple threads, but constraint being - the thread that processes the data from a given source should always continue to process the data from that source.

I used a SingleThreadExecutor that takes a Q and used a consistent hash type approach where the source's hash % 10 is mapped to a thread that processes the data.

Only concern here is hashing may not be uniform and some threads may be more loaded than others.
Is there any better ways or achieving this?
Has anyone tried a similar design problem? What are some of the suggestions that could be tried to get uniform spread of load of data across given set of Queues or threads?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain that same-thread constraint? It's atypical in multiple ways and sounds like an XY constraint.

Comment: Say for example i have 5 sources that produce the data, A, B, C, D and E and I have 3 Queues that are consumers of these data, and each Q has a worker thread assigned to it so that data can be processed when Q has data. If I start putting data from source A on Q1 and source C on Q2, subsequent data from A has to be put on Q1 and data from Chas to be put on Q2 only. This is what i meant by same thread constraint.

Comment: I'll be more specific: Explain _why_ you have (or believe you have) that constraint. It indicates an underlying design problem that can probably be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `online problem`. Since you do not know in advance how much processing each source will require, you can't achieve perfect balancing.

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you're describing as your solution, so my next few lines might be a duplication of what you've already said:

I would hold in some data structure a mapping of source/process where I would also keep the number of current number of jobs waiting on that process (from all sources).

When a new source appears I'd assign it to the process which has the smallest load.

In severe cases (e.g., only three sources left active, and all three are on the same process), I would queue the incoming jobs (temporarily) and when the process has finished handling the jobs it already in its queue I would re-distribute the source/process mapping.

Hope this makes sense and is useful.

Comment: how would you determine the queue with smallest load?

Comment: Also what is the best way to distribute load starting with the first request coming in is my main question? What algorithms are commonly used? I know one such algo is ConistentHashing, but any popular algorithms for round-robin etc?

Comment: To keep track of the loads on the queues, keep an object with the queue ID and how many tasks are waiting on it. (when adding a task, increase,  when finished, decrease)